# Update browser as each file is uploaded to server

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, upload

I have a page where users can add attachments to emails. When they click to start uploading their attachments, I run a bit of javascript to set a label to read (for example) 'Uploading File 1 of 4'

The code that handles the upload is below. As each file is saved, I want to update the browser label to read (for example) 'File 1 uploaded. Uploading File 2 of 4'. Etc.

What technique can I use to keep the browser notified as the files are updated? I don't need a progress bar.

```
HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
{
HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
    hpf.SaveAs(path + ReturnValue.ToString() + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
    //This is where I want to update the browser so the user is informed as each file is uploaded
    }
}
```

I tried using Response.Write to write `<script type="text/javascript">alert('File 1 uploaded')</script>` just to see if that would do anything. But it does not work.

I tried using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript` to call a function but that didn't work.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck? What ideas did you consider?

Comment: I tried using Response.Write to write <script type="text/javascript">alert('File 1 uploaded')</script>; and Response.Flush(); just to see if that would do anything. But it does not work.

I tried using ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript to call a function but that didn't work.

No idea what to try to be honest, never needed to do this before. Normally I write things to the browser after whatever I am doing on the server has finished.

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach to this is to use AJAX to poll a web method on the server side - this is a method that would return the current data.

One issue with this is that the server may be using session synchronisation, so you will need to use a sessionless web method.

Comment: As I understand it a Web Method is a method of a web service - sorry I don't understand. I could probably work out how to use AJAX to poll a web method - but what would that web method do? How would it know anything about the files I am uploading?

Comment: @MartinSmellworse - You would need to have some shared data that such a method can pick up and that your web page updates.